# Sessions don't work when connecting to rails rest service with c# via RestSharp

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, session

I am using C# with RestSharp to make some calls to a rails application.
But it seems the session variables are not saved when doing this. It works fine when using a normal browser to make the calls.

This is my call in c#

```
 public void createUser(String firstname, String lastname, String password)
        {
            RestClient client = new RestClient("http://localhost:3000");
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest("users/login/{firstname}/{lastname}/{password}", Method.GET);
            request.AddUrlSegment("firstname", "admin");
            request.AddUrlSegment("lastname", "admin");
            request.AddUrlSegment("password", "admin");

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var content = response.Content;

            RestRequest request2 = new RestRequest("users/create/{firstname}/{lastname}/{password}", Method.GET);
            request2.AddUrlSegment("firstname", "this");
            request2.AddUrlSegment("lastname", "will");
            request2.AddUrlSegment("password", "work");

            response = client.Execute(request2);
            content = response.Content;
            MessageBox.Show(content);

        }
```

And here are the rails methods:

```
 def create
    firstname = params[:firstname]
    lastname = params[:lastname]
    pwd = params[:password]
    @user = User.new({:firstname => firstname, :lastname => lastname, :password => pwd })
    @userloggedin = User.find(session[:user_id])

    if(@userloggedin.is_admin == 1)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @user.save
          format.html { redirect_to "http://google.com" }
          format.json { render json: "user created" } 
        end
      end



    end
  end






  def login
    firstname = params[:firstname]
    lastname = params[:lastname]
    password = params[:password]

    @user = User.where("firstname = ? AND lastname = ?", firstname, lastname).first

    if(@user && @user.password == password)
      session[:loggedin] = true
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to "http://google.com" }
        format.json { render json: "accpeted" }
      end
    else

      respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to "http://google.com" }
          format.json { render json: "not accpeted" }
    end

  end
```

WHen making the second call in c# i get:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound\n in UsersController#create\n

Couldn't find User without an ID

because the session variable was not saved.

Is there any way to make it work with a nonbrowser client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to preserve Session, the client needs to hold the information. Browsers do it via cookies.

For RestSharp, try using `CookieContainer` to hold the cookie information between calls. Reference [here](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Cookies)